# Spring : NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, spring, maven

I was trying to rearrange my pom.xml to resolve some problem in my application and a new error appeared when in run a Maven Install :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/bloombooking/spring/PersistenceJPAConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/tool/schema/spi/DelayedDropRegistry
```

I don't know how i've messed up with it to create that and i can't find help anywhere...
Here is my pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.bloombooking</groupId>
  <artifactId>bloombookingapi</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>bloombookingapi</name>
  <description></description>

  <properties>
     <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
     <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>

  <parent>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
     <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <dependencies>

     <!-- Servlet api -->
     <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
     </dependency>

     <!-- Spring context -->
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
     </dependency>
     <!-- Spring orm -->
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
     </dependency>
     <!-- Spring boot web-->
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
     </dependency>
     <!-- Spring boot test-->
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
     <!-- Spring boot jpa-->
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
     </dependency>
     <!-- Spring jersey -->
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
     </dependency>

     <!-- Hibernate -->
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
     </dependency>

     <!-- PostgreSQL -->
     <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
     </dependency>

     <!-- Log4j -->
     <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
     </dependency>

     <!-- Junit -->
     <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
     </dependency>

     <!-- Gson -->
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
     </dependency>

     <!-- JavaMail -->
     <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
     </dependency>

     <!-- Jersey Java WS RS -->
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.2</version>
     </dependency>

     <!-- Apache commons codec (for easy SHA256 parsing) -->
     <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
     </dependency>


  </dependencies>

  <build>
     <plugins>

        <!-- Maven compiler with java 1.8 -->
        <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>3.1</version>
           <configuration>
              <source>1.8</source>
              <target>1.8</target>
           </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
     </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Can someone give me some help ? 
Thanks

Comment: If you're using Spring Boot, is there a particular reason for doing all of that configuration manually instead of just using the JPA starter?

Comment: What do you mean by "all of that configuration manually" ? Using PersistenceJPAConfig.java ?

Comment: Yes. That entire class can be replaced by four lines in `application.properties`, which will also make it easier to inject JDBC connection information at runtime.

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice, i've done it but the error remain the same. (I've also deleted the class from the first post)

Comment: Have you done a complete clean and rebuild?

Comment: Yes i did it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to specify dependencies for spring-context,spring-orm and hibernate-entitymanager in you pom.xml as you are using Spring Boot starter web and jpa dependencies which will pull the required jar files. Please cleanup your pom file. Class `DelayedDropRegistry` for which you are getting NoClassDefFoundError is available in hibernate-core jar file since 5.1 release. Check your local maven repository for the hibernate-core jar files and versions. You can use maven > update project to update dependencies and clean build your project. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thx @abaghel you resolved my problem and even explain what was wrong :)